# How can I parse the following JSON for WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, constraints

In addition ,I would recommend that please refer the link below for a similar thread which provides some solutions for the same issue.

Problem deserializing JSON in a Silverlight program

Hope it can help you.

Comment: this json does not contain date information. what date do you need?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for json deserialization and [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) for getting data purposes.

Here is a piece of my code where I'm using DataContractJsonSerializer:

```
    //...
    if (CheckError((HttpWebResponse) webResponse)) return;

    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Message[]), new[] { typeof(Message) });
    var stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
    _networkMessages = (Message[])serializer.ReadObject(stream);
    //...
```

Comment: Can you please redirect me a simple demo? where i can put my xxxx.json  webservice link and get data?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm run into such sample, but even if it is so, I don't have a link - just see example in the link I've gave you